# Are callbacks once per session, or once per session for each previous Episode?

Tags: cortex-plus, firefly

On page 256 of the core rulebook it says:

> You can only use a callback once per Episode, but at the end of each
>   Episode, the callbacks refresh. You are then free to use them again in
>   the next Episode.

It says you only get one callback per Episode but I'm not sure if that's referring to once per the Episode actually being played or once per Episode that has previously passed. The first phrase seems to refer to the current Episode, not each previous episode that is listed in your sheet, but then it says “callbacks” and “them”, plural, which suggests an interpretation that there might be more than one used.

So do you get one per session or one per session per previous Episode?

Comment: Where is the plural that your last edit talks about?

Comment: The callback(s) refresh. Indicates multiple callbacks.

Comment: Also the use of the word them, instead of it.

Comment: So is a simpler way to state the question, “How many callbacks do you get to use per session?”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use each episode in your Episode Guide as a callback one time during your play of the current episode. So if you are playing Episode 4, you can make 3 callbacks, one to each of Episodes 1, 2, and 3, before you're out of callbacks. Then, when you finish Episode 4 and start Episode 5, all of the Episodes in your Guide refresh, and you've got 4 of them to use in Episode 5.

Pages 107 and 133 spell it out much more thoroughly, and give examples.

It's a kind of experience metric. Rather than building up XP like you'd get in a traditional RPG, you get this ever increasing pool of refreshable Plot Point-like callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

From the text quoted, it seems reasonably clear to me - each callback should be usable once per Episode. The fact that it says callbacks (plural) refresh at the end of each Episode reinforces this.

Comment: I think you've missed the heart of the question. Suppose I have two Episodes in my Episode guide. Can I make a callback to each one while playing in the current Episode? Or can I only make a single callback? In other words, does "once per Episode" mean "each callback in your Episode Guide can be used once" or "you can make one callback each time you play an Episode?"

Comment: do you have anything to corroborate your interpretation, perhaps another quote from the book or a subsequent publication? If  not could you back up your statement with example from play that explain why this version seems to fit more than the other interpretation?

Comment: Never played the game, don't own the book, purely reading the text quoted...feel free to add a more accurate answer yourself.